# How the scrapy on python3 can get text datas working on the javascript

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/

[image]

In this page, I try to get a time info from some time text like '14 days ago'.

In the browser, when I move a mouse point to that text, it show the date-time based information. But if I view the web page source, I can't find it. So I think it work based on Javascript.

I am not web-developer, and I'm not sure how can I trace the problem.

My question is: how can I trace the data working based on the javascript using chrome dev-tools and scrapy shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Reddit's read-only (no participation) subdomain:

https://np.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/

Note that it is `np` and not `www`. In this view you get the full date and time in the HTML in the `<time>` tag (in any browser) without running Javascript:
[image: time tag]

Example:

```
scrapy shell 'https://np.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/'

>>> response.css('time::attr(datetime)').get()
'2010-03-02T22:52:12+00:00'
```

Comment: I thought it made based on dynamic site.
hmm... is it managing multi-web-browsing by domain forwarding?
I don't understand. How it show on "https://np.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/".
does 'raddit' serve above domain service? or it is some another read-only web-site service solution?

Comment: If you know that answer, could you tell me why? please :D

Comment: Both domains belong to Reddit. They serve different HTML and Javascript on different subdomains (but still the same content). I am not sure if they do automatic redirection. But basically, just use the `np` version.

Comment: thank you for your answer. It shold made upgrading my knowledge. :D

Answer (score 1):

```sh
$ scrapy shell https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/
```

...

```py
>>> response.css('[data-click-id="timestamp"]::text').get()
'15 days ago'
```

Comment: This is not what the question is looking for.  When you hover over the "X days ago" text it displays a popup with the full date and time. That data is not available directly in the HTML unless you trigger the Javascript event.

Comment: when you try to move the mouse over that word, it show such as "thu feb 07 2019......."
I want to get that informations
and it show that infomation on  the explorer using time and title tag.... omg

Comment: @malberts I assume that only show the information working based on html by explorer. but chrome is different.. It naver show time tag and information... So I guess it working with javascript.

Comment: @bluebamus Yes, it is showing the popup text with Javascript. The full date/time is not hidden in the HTML. Instead it is stored in Javascript objects which you cannot access directly from Scrapy.

Answer (score 0):

Reddit has an [official API](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/). When that is the case I would seriously consider using it instead of HTML scraping.

On the other hand, if you *really* want to do HTML scraping then I would suggest you use something like [Scrapy Splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) to trigger that Javascript. Trying to find the raw data hidden away in Javascript objects probably isn't worth the effort. Especially if the Javascript does additional processing which you'll need to replicate because it won't run on plain Scrapy anyway.

Comment: thanks bro. before check it by explorer, I assumed that is working based on javascript. but not now... I confuse. chrome dev-tools doesn't show a time tag but exploerer dev-tools show it.... even I use scrapy splash, is it can detect the time information? ...

Comment: @bluebamus Scrapy Splash can execute Javascript. So you will send it a command to hover over the "X days ago" text and then you can get the text. When you hover it adds a `<div>` at the bottom of the HTML which contains the full text you want.

Comment: @bluebamus Can you add a screen of how Explorer dev tools shows it?

Comment: sure! I did. it show the time and title tag... So, I am confusing.. How chrome work for that...  I'm not sure that chrome html code use a javascript...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

this picture result captured on the explorer.

Comment: I found a solution. I will write a new answer.

Comment: it is same url result for "https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/". and can u check that result with chrome dev-tools?

Comment: oh.. reply changed... :D